# Ideas for 2d fire simulation

Tags: 2d, algorithm, physics

I want to simulate a fire in a flat and non flat* surface (fire spread modelling).

I've seen that cellular automata is one of the algorithms that can be used. Are there other algorithms that would be interesting to test?

*adding some barriers like walls

Comment: This isn't the place for discussions. See the [FAQ](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/faq) about what kinds of questions to ask here.

Comment: I would recommend rephrasing to something along the lines of "What methods for simulating fire in 2d exist other than cellular automata?" to make Byte happy.

Comment: I'm not sure that rephrasing would work. Since then the *correct* answer would need to include all the methods for simulating fire in 2D. It's still a discussion/polling for ideas. Just like asking what [2D engines exist for C++](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/37519/what-2d-game-engines-are-there-available-for-c). @A.R. You should totally ask in chat though, discussions are welcome there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy. Particle system. Flammable objects have a constant boolean for flammability set to True, then another boolean which dictates if the object is on fire. If true spawn a particle system on them to give it an effect which makes it look like its on fire. If a flaming object collides with another, then set that object on fire. You may want to spread the flame only after the objects have made contact for a certain duration, or all connected flammable objects would light instantly.

I've done something similar with the [Love2D Engine](http://love2d.org)